# XJC - XSDs with elements that have the same name - already defined error

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

I’m trying to understand what I need to consider if I want to generate java classes from a set of `xsd-schemas` using `jaxb`. An unsolved problem I get during my present attempts was caused by a name conflict:

> „[ERROR] 'attempt_data' is already defined“, the element „attempt data“ can be found in two xsd-files

Because of that I created an external binding customization file – according to the documentation offered by oracle („Customizing JAXB Bindings“). thought, this is the way to resolve such a name collision and that this should solve it. But now I’m not sure if this it the right way. The mentioned error still appeared during the following parsing attempts.

**xsd 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>This is just an attempt (1).</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="attempt_data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**xsd 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>This is just an attempt (2).</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="attempt_data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**jaxb_ebf.xjb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="file_01.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='attemptdata']">
            <jxb:class name="attemptdatap"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings> 
</jxb:bindings>
```

**command line**

```
xjc file directory  –b Binding-File
```

i appreciate any kind of advice – thanks in advance

Comment: Since you declared to appreciate any kind of advice ... :D. My advice would be (assuming you are doing this for a production codebase) to not generate any data model classes from schemas. Instead development them separately. The effort is one-time or very marginally incremental. The benefit are many, especially from the perspective of maintenance. In addition, the time and effort expended is very minimal to develop a data model with JAXB annotations vis-a-vis understand, implement and debug JAXB mapping files. It will help in long run.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks! But to be honest: Is there really no way to resolve the name conflict? Is there any source for further information?

Comment: Try this, user separate namespaces for both of your schema 'targetNamespace'. Declare 2 separate bindings with different 'schemaLocation', use different class names for the bindings, e.g., attemptdata & attemptdata1. The problem you are facing is because primarily you have 2 declaration of the same element (same name) in the same namespace in your case default namespace, not permit. Try to separate them out with targetNamespace and in any generated code base 2 files cannot have same name; my guess is one will overwrite the other. With coded data model, it is very easy to get round this problem

Comment: Thanks! I'm late again, turbulent times. So it is not possible for me to generate classes using xjc without changing the xsd-files, because the set of files i need to parse often uses the same targetnamespace and some files have the declaration of the same element. This again is the cause of the shown "already defined"-error.

I wrongly accepted that i could resolve that problem with the correct use of the external binding file.

Packages also didn't worked out.
`code`<jxb:package name="mytargetnamespaceA"/>`code`